# Separate the domain with landing page and web app in AWS managed service

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-api-gateway

I wanna put my landing page in HTML into S3 and running my react web app in Lambda. The configuration that I wish is like the following.

1. [www.my-own-bm.com](http://www.my-own-bm.com) => S3 landing page
2. [www.my-own-bm.com/introduction](http://www.my-own-bm.com/introduction) => sub landing page in S3. There are several sub landing page.
3. [www.my-own-bm.com/signin](http://www.my-own-bm.com/signin), signup... => react app on lambda

I suppose Route53 or API Gateway can resolve such an issue. Please share your knowledge or experience if you have met or resolved.

Comment: You can not do this using Route 53. Not sure if it can be accomplished by API GW but it can definitely be accomplished using an Application Load Balancer with which you can do Path based Routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register your domain name with route 53,
then create a CloudFront distribution, and add the domain to CloudFront Alternate Domain Names.

Add your s3 bucket as an origin, redirect to it in the behavior tab for the
"/introduction" path

For the "/signin" path pattern use your CloudFront distribution as a trigger for your lambda, you should select us-east-1 to be able to deploy your lambda@edge function